# getBoundingClientRect().top value is inconsistent on safari browser on iphone

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, mobile-safari, getboundingclientrect

I am having a scroll event listener in my web application.Inside the scroll event listener, I tried to calculate the `getBoundingClientRect().top` value of a scrolling element. This value is consistent and correct in all browsers except safari browser in IOS application.If we scroll a little fast this value goes all over the place.Is this a bug in safari browser on IOS or is there any hack around.

IOS version - 17.2.1

Comment: Can you include the code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?